# How to add multi value in same case

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case, multivalue

i have problems when adding mullti values into same case:

this is my c# code

```
string input = combobox1.selectedvalue.ToString(); 
switch(input)
{
case "one";
     return 1;
     break;
case "two";
     return 2;
     break;
case "three" , "four":   // error here
     return 34;
     break;
default:
     return 0;
}
```

need your help for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use separate labels:

```
string input = combobox1.selectedvalue.ToString(); 
switch(input)
{
case "one":
     return 1;
     break;
case "two":
     return 2;
     break;
case "three": 
case "four":
     return 34;
     break;
default:
     return 0;
}
```

See [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx):

> Each switch section contains one or more *case labels* followed by one or more statements

Comment: You don't even need the `break`s, because you have a `return` in each switch section.

Answer (score 1):

You can you the fall though, read [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/case) for more information 
so it's look like this

```
switch(input)
{
case "one":
     return 1;
     break;
case "two":
     return 2;
     break;
case "three":
case "four": 
     return 34;
     break;
default:
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: fall through is traditionally used to indicate that code in a particular section will run and then (in the absence of `break`) will continue into the next section. That's not, precisely, how `switch` is defined in C# and actual fall-through isn't allowed

Comment: See [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx): "unlike some other languages, your code may not fall through into the next switch section"

Comment: There is no _fall through_ in this code. Its just a _switch section_ with multiple _case labels_. So Damien's comments are off topic. Only problem with the original version was the `;` at the end of the case label instead of a `:`

Comment: @CarstenHeine - my comments were, specifically, pointing out that the use of the phrase "fall through" in this answer were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Right syntax is

```
case "three": 
case "four":
     return 34;
     break;
```

instead

```
case "three" , "four": 
     return 34;
     break;
```

From [`switch` (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

> A switch statement includes one or more switch sections. Each switch
>   section contains one or more case labels **followed by one or more
>   statements.**